# How can I determine if a function generates a graph

Tags: graphics, r

Is there a way to determine if a function generates a figure in **R**?

For example, if we have functions *f* and *g*

```
f = function(x,y){plot(x,y)}
g = function(x,y){mean(x*y)}
```

I would like able to run

```
createFigure(f(x,y))#Returns TRUE
createFigure(g(x,y))#Returns FALSE
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW Colin, I am curious as to how such a function might be useful? Best, Tal

Comment: Students submit some functions as coursework. One of their functions should produce a graph. 

I then use Sweave to run their coursework and check for correctness. However, if the function is incorrect and doesn't produce any graphics I can't compile the resulting tex file.

Comment: IMHO, this is the most underrated question on SO's R section. Thanks for asking, and @hadley, thanks for saving the day! =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
makes_plot <- function(x) {
  before <- .Internal(getSnapshot())
  force(x)
  after <- .Internal(getSnapshot())
  !identical(before, after)
}

makes_plot(mean(1:10))
makes_plot(plot(1:10))
```

The `.getSnapshot` function was discovered by looking at the source of `recordPlot()`.

Comment: +1 Maybe include that in ggplot2 so that it's readily available?

Comment: Nice! (fulfilling min(length(comment))

Comment: Very nice Hadley... not that this also returns true for lines(), points(), grid(), and axis() when they aren't used to actually make a plot, only add to one.  Perhaps it's true for all commands that modify plots.

Answer (score 0):

If, for your purposes, it's OK to have all devices off before hand then checking .Devices would be fine because then plotting commands do make a new device.  But then lines(), and points() would be exceptions.

In fact, this suggests that the question doesn't just have a true or false answer but depends on conditions.  Some functions will draw something even if there is no open device while others will draw something if there is something else drawn.  What would you want to do in that case?

Comment: I have a Sweave document that calls the function. If a graph is created I include it in the Tex file.

The functions come from students.