# Capture generated plots and objects from R code chunk

Tags: r

Note that I'm aware of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743466/how-can-i-determine-if-a-function-generates-a-graph). I'd just like to know if there's a way to "detect" not only graphs, but also generated objects. For instance, if we have this code chunk:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
plot(x)
y <- round(runif(100))
crl <- cor.test(x, y)
boxplot(x ~ y)
```

there are three objects (two numeric vectors: `x` and `y`, one `htest`-class object), and two plots (an index plot of variable `x`, and boxplot of `x` over "levels" of `y`). Is it possible to attach some hooks that operate in a different manner on vectors/plots?

And here comes even nastier scenario - what if you don't assign stuff to objects? What if you just evaluate them?

```
x <- rnorm(10)
plot(x)
runif(10)
```

Is there any way to, e.g. evaluate this code in a separate environment, and record snapshot of environment's contents before and after evaluation, then compare states of two snapshots, and store generated stuff, say to a list, in latter case something like this:

```
list(
    x = c(0.0571094065969082, -0.644536546605725, 0.342691062512616, 0.348529238626249, 2.19101790784795, 1.43065640761249, -0.230245257207684, 0.0768174872901325, 0.965715513349098, -0.607450090812782),
    `plot(x)` = "<path/to/plot>",
    `runif(10)` = c(0.11007297760807, 0.843735514208674, 0.620932232355699, 0.622749823378399, 0.852932719048113, 0.435453998856246, 0.231673048110679, 0.820609186775982, 0.0562138997483999, 0.823565979953855)
    )
```

---

This rant is similar, but not identical to [issue #50](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/50) of `knitr` package.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on **why** you feel the need to do this?

Comment: I think that _[issue #50](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/50)_ on `knitr` GitHub page will disclose my intentions. (**Disclaimer:** *it's not cross-posting, it's cross-referencing*) =)

Comment: Have you looked at the evaluate package?  That's designed to do almost exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks @hadley, Yihui Xie pointed me on that one, I'm still checking it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was hard to understand (for me) but based on @hadley's package I tried to implement a lame function for that:

```
parser <- function(txt) {
    tmp <- new.env()
    lapply(txt, function(src) {
        #produces.graph <- function(x) any(sapply(x, function(x) any(class(x) == "recordedplot")))
        clear.devs <- function() while (!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off(as.numeric(dev.list()))

        clear.devs()
        file <- tempfile()
        png(file)

        eval <- evaluate(src, envir = tmp)
        #graph <- produces.graph(eval)
        graph <- ifelse(is.na(file.info(file)$size), FALSE, file)
        returns <- ifelse(length(eval) > 1, TRUE, FALSE)
        if (returns & is.logical(graph)) returns <- eval(parse(text=src), envir = tmp)
        if (is.character(graph)) returns <- graph
        clear.devs()
        return(list(src=src, returns=returns))
        }
    )
}
```

This function takes only one argument: lines of text to check and parse. It will return the `src` of those lines and the output of the evaluated `src`. If a graph is returned, it says: "graph!". Based on that this lame solution can be extended.

Demo run:

```
library(evaluate)
library(ggplot2)

txt <- readLines(textConnection('x <- rnorm(100)
runif(10)
plot(1:10)
qplot(rating, data=movies, geom="histogram")
y <- round(runif(100))
cor.test(x, y)
crl <- cor.test(runif(10), runif(10))
table(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl)'))
```

Output:

```
> parser(txt)
[[1]]
[[1]]$src
[1] "x <- rnorm(100)"

[[1]]$returns
[1] FALSE


[[2]]
[[2]]$src
[1] "runif(10)"

[[2]]$returns
 [1] 0.095131 0.458321 0.866366 0.494758 0.429026 0.417446 0.465919 0.980345 0.376258 0.143056


[[3]]
[[3]]$src
[1] "plot(1:10)"

[[3]]$returns
[1] "/tmp/RtmpWUJnzu/file6e9d997f"


[[4]]
[[4]]$src
[1] "qplot(rating, data=movies, geom=\"histogram\")"

[[4]]$returns
[1] "/tmp/RtmpWUJnzu/file6116e1ee"


[[5]]
[[5]]$src
[1] "y <- round(runif(100))"

[[5]]$returns
[1] FALSE


[[6]]
[[6]]$src
[1] "cor.test(x, y)"

[[6]]$returns

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  x and y 
t = 0.3742, df = 98, p-value = 0.7091
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.15984  0.23246 
sample estimates:
     cor 
0.037768 



[[7]]
[[7]]$src
[1] "crl <- cor.test(runif(10), runif(10))"

[[7]]$returns
[1] FALSE


[[8]]
[[8]]$src
[1] "table(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl)"

[[8]]$returns

     4  6  8
  0  3  4 12
  1  8  3  2
```

I am aware of the fact that this is an ugly, unoptimal and not all-out answer, but had great time while trying to find a solution :)

**Update:** added separate environment & saving generated plots to files.

---

**Update [2013/05/23]**: I know this is a pretty old question, but as I was working on similar problems in the last two years it might be worth mentioning -- that the `evals` function in [`pander` package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#evals) can help with this issue. Demo:

```
> str(evals(txt))
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
List of 8
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "x <- rnorm(100)"
  ..$ result: NULL
  ..$ output: NULL
  ..$ type  : chr "NULL"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "runif(10)"
  ..$ result: num [1:10] 0.095 0.261 0.349 0.765 0.529 ...
  ..$ output: chr [1:2] " [1] 0.09499242 0.26139848 0.34917008 0.76512684 0.52886251 0.98015282 0.76929669 0.65701019" " [9] 0.06849910 0.71962828"
  ..$ type  : chr "numeric"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "plot(1:10)"
  ..$ result:Class 'image'  chr "plots/d8572a18a8a.png"
  ..$ output: NULL
  ..$ type  : chr "image"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "qplot(rating, data = movies, geom = \"histogram\")"
  ..$ result:Class 'image'  chr "plots/d85673ce008.png"
  ..$ output: chr(0) 
  ..$ type  : chr "image"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "y <- round(runif(100))"
  ..$ result: NULL
  ..$ output: NULL
  ..$ type  : chr "NULL"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "cor.test(x, y)"
  ..$ result:List of 9
  .. ..$ statistic  : Named num -0.202
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
  .. ..$ parameter  : Named int 98
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
  .. ..$ p.value    : num 0.84
  .. ..$ estimate   : Named num -0.0204
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "cor"
  .. ..$ null.value : Named num 0
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "correlation"
  .. ..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
  .. ..$ method     : chr "Pearson's product-moment correlation"
  .. ..$ data.name  : chr "x and y"
  .. ..$ conf.int   : atomic [1:2] -0.216 0.177
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
  ..$ output: chr [1:12] "" "\tPearson's product-moment correlation" "" "data:  x and y" ...
  ..$ type  : chr "htest"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "crl <- cor.test(runif(10), runif(10))"
  ..$ result: NULL
  ..$ output: NULL
  ..$ type  : chr "NULL"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "table(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl)"
  ..$ result: 'table' int [1:2, 1:3] 3 8 4 3 12 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "4" "6" "8"
  ..$ output: chr [1:4] "   " "     4  6  8" "  0  3  4 12" "  1  8  3  2"
  ..$ type  : chr "table"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
```

Comment: yeah, by creating a new (blank) environment beforehand, and evaluating stuff there.

Comment: now this yields another question: how to detect if user plots multiple graphs in the same chunk? what if my graph spans on multiple lines? you'll have to check "something magical" in the device to catch that... if that's at all possible. `ggplot` and like provide more control over graph creation...

Comment: I've updated my answer to `eval` in separate environment and return paths to plots. About multiple plots: that a shame, but I will not try to solve that problem :) Parse texts where all plotting stuff is a one-liner (even with concatenating the lines with `;`).